# Повторное использование скрипта в цикле JavaScript. Сервлеты Java

Tags: javascript, java-ee, jsp, servlet, jstl

Сервлет помещает в `session` какую-то информацию. Необходимо вывести ее с новой строки, после каждой строки должен быть `checkbox` и `button` загрузки файла.

Так выглядит `checkbox` и `button` для загрузки файла:

```
<c:ForEach ......>
    <input type="checkbox" name="id" value="${task.id}">
    <input type="file" id="fileCheck" name="file" style="display:none;"/>
    <input type="button" id="chooseButtonCheck" value="&#9998;" onclick="document.getElementById('fileCheck').click();"/>
</c:forEach>
```

`script` прилагается:

```
<script>
    var fileButton = document.getElementById("fileCheck");
    fileButton.onchange = updateButtonName.bind(fileButton);
    function updateButtonName(){
        var chooseButton = document.getElementById("chooseButtonCheck");
        chooseButton.value = this.files.item(0).name;
    }
</script>
```

В итоге по нажатию на `button` можно выбрать файл. После того, как файл будет выбран, значение кнопки изменится на имя файла(на самой кнопке будет написано file.jpg, например). Все отлично работает ВНЕ цикла.

В цикле отрабатывает только первая строка. Попытка прикрепить файл к последующим строкам подменяют файл в первой строке.

Как можно проделать тот же финт ушами с каждой строкой в цикле, чтобы в случае прикрепления файла к нескольким строкам, везде отображалось своё имя файла на `button`'e?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID элементов должны быть уникальны. Поэтому в данном случае имеет смысл переключиться с ID на классы.

При минимальном изменении верстки (`<div>`-ы добавлены только для наглядности) можно сделать так:

```js
var fileChecks = document.getElementsByClassName("fileCheck");
var chooseButtons = document.getElementsByClassName("chooseButtonCheck");

for (var i = 0; i < chooseButtons.length; i++) {
  (function(index) {
    var chooseButton = chooseButtons[index];
    var fileCheck = fileChecks[index];

    chooseButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
      fileCheck.click();
    });

    fileCheck.addEventListener("change", function() {
        chooseButton.value = this.files.item(0).name;
    });
  })(i);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="id" value="id1">
  <input type="file" class="fileCheck" name="file" style="display: none;"/>
  <input type="button" class="chooseButtonCheck" value="&#9998;" />
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="id" value="id2">
  <input type="file" class="fileCheck" name="file" style="display: none;"/>
  <input type="button" class="chooseButtonCheck" value="&#9998;" />
</div>
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="id" value="id3">
  <input type="file" class="fileCheck" name="file" style="display: none;"/>
  <input type="button" class="chooseButtonCheck" value="&#9998;" />
</div>
```

Comment: Пошел курить js, спасибо большое!